# how to add an extra string or key/value pair only for some specific log message in java spring boot project

Tags: java, spring-boot, log4j, log4j2

In my spring boot application, we need to add an extra tag( key/value pair) only for some specific log messages to highlight that these are some special purpose logs and not for others.

Project log4j2.xml configuration:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="WARN">
   <Appenders>
        <Console name="console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
          <JsonTemplateLayout eventTemplateUri="classpath:LogstashLayout.json">
          </JsonTemplateLayout>
        </Console>
    </Appenders>
   <Loggers>
      <AsyncRoot level="info" additivity="false">
         <AppenderRef ref="console" />
      </AsyncRoot>
   </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

What is the standard recommended approach to do this? is this need to be done some sort of filter configurations?

Comment: What qualifies a message as special? Does it depend on the context (the same message is sometimes tagged, sometimes not), logger (all messages from a specific logger) or should specific log statements always be marked?

Comment: Specific log statements should always be having an extra tag if a boolean flag is enabled .

Comment: The question is unclear. What boolean flag, where do you specify it? Why not just add the key/value pair to the log statements that need it?

Answer (score 3):

Think that [marker](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/markers.html) would be helpful to you although it can just tag a log message but cannot add a key/value to it. After you use it to tag the log messages , you can configure a [filter](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/filters.html#markerfilter) in the configuration to determine whether a message with certain tag should be displayed or not.

For example, you can tag the log messages something like:

```java
public class Foo {

    private static final Marker TAG1 = MarkerManager.getMarker("TAG1");
    private static final Marker TAG2 = MarkerManager.getMarker("TAG2");
    private static final Marker TAG3 = MarkerManager.getMarker("TAG3");

    void test(){

        log.info(TAG1, "message with tag1");
        log.info(TAG1, "message with tag1");
        log.info(TAG2, "message with tag2");
        log.info(TAG2, "message with tag2");
        log.info(TAG3, "message with tag3");
        log.info(TAG3, "message with tag3");

    }
}
```

Then with this filter configuration :

```xml
  <Appenders>
    <Console name="Console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
      <PatternLayout pattern="%d{ISO8601} |%t| %5p | %c{1} | %L | %m%n" />
      <Filters>
        <MarkerFilter marker="TAG1" onMatch="ACCEPT" onMismatch="NEUTRAL"/>
        <MarkerFilter marker="TAG2" onMatch="ACCEPT" onMismatch="NEUTRAL"/>
        <MarkerFilter marker="TAG3" onMatch="DENY" onMismatch="NEUTRAL"/>
      </Filters>>
    </Console>
  </Appenders>
```

Only messages with `TAG1` , `TAG2` and no tags will be displayed to console. Messages with `TAG3` will not.

And if the filter configuration is :

```xml
  <Appenders>
    <Console name="Console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
      <PatternLayout pattern="%d{ISO8601} |%t| %5p | %c{1} | %L | %m%n" />
      <Filters>
        <MarkerFilter marker="TAG1" onMatch="ACCEPT" onMismatch="NEUTRAL"/>
        <MarkerFilter marker="TAG2" onMatch="ACCEPT" onMismatch="NEUTRAL"/>
        <MarkerFilter marker="TAG3" onMatch="DENY" onMismatch="DENY"/>
      </Filters>>
    </Console>
  </Appenders>
```

Then only messages with `TAG1` , `TAG2` will be displayed. Messages with  `TAG3` or no tags will not.

The filter can be configured at the logger level or appender level. And I found this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60130230/339637) is helpful to understand the basic idea of how does the filter works.

Comment: Are we saying that Marker is only used for filtering the log messages and not to add extra string tag into the logs?

Comment: well think that you can use `%marker` to also display the maker name in the log if you like.  https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/layouts.html#pattern-layout

Answer (score 1):

You can create another Custom class which handles addition of an extra tag (key/value) pair in logging mechanism.

```
import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.Configurator;
import org.json.simple.JSONObject;

public class CustomLogger {

private static CustomLogger instance = null;
private static final Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(CustomLogger.class);  
private final static CustomLogger log = CustomLogger.getLogger();

private CustomLogger() {
    super();
}

public static CustomLogger getLogger(){  
    if(instance==null){   
        instance = new CustomLogger();
        //Configurator.setAllLevels(logger.getName(), org.apache.logging.log4j.Level.ALL);
    }   
    return instance;
}

public void info(String msg) {
    logger.info(msg);

}

public void info(JSONObject obj, String msg) {
    // Add your key/value 
    logger.info("["+obj+"]" + msg);
 }
}
```

You can use this custom class along with the normal log mechanism.

```
import org.json.simple.JSONObject;

public class CustomLoggerMain {

private static final Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(CustomLoggerMain.class);  

public static void main(String[] args) {
    
    CustomLogger log = CustomLogger.getLogger();
    JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
    obj.put("test", "logger-test");
    log.info(obj, "Msg with extra key pair");

    //Configurator.setAllLevels(logger.getName(), org.apache.logging.log4j.Level.ALL);
    logger.info("Normal Logger");
 }
}
```

Hope this solution will solve the problem or provide you an idea how to deal with the situation. It's a basic example you can customize according to your requirements or project.